# change FloatingActionButton and SubActionButton background color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Is it possible to change the background color of android Floating Action Button and Sub ActionButton when using min APi 16?

I have tried a lot of different situations like:

```
actionButton.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.myColor));
```

But all say that the min API level is 16 and required is 21.

Is there a way to do it in API level 16 programmatically in the Java file?

Comment: Use AppCompat. And don't tag with Android STudio, this isn't an AS issue

Comment: sorry, was inadvertently.

Comment: getResources is deprecated use "ContextCompat"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Change the floating action bar color, just write this in your xml

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/desired_color"
```

and in java is

```
actionButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, your color)));
```

Comment: I have tried this already. But this solution requires minimum API level of 21 and I need minimum API Level 16.

Comment: use this library https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton   require api lv 14+

Comment: thanks a lot for this library. It solves all problems that I was having with FAB

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```